# classification report for adapters with transformers

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I used this code, but I want to calculate classification report especially f1 score but I donnot kow how todo that

```
import numpy as np
from transformers import TrainingArguments, AdapterTrainer, EvalPrediction

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    learning_rate=3e-4,
    max_steps=80000,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    logging_steps=1000,
    output_dir="adapter-roberta-base-amazon-polarity",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
)
def compute_accuracy(eval_pred):
  preds = np.argmax(eval_pred.predictions, axis=1)
  return {"acc": (preds == eval_pred.label_ids).mean(),"f1":f1_score(preds == eval_pred.label_ids)}
trainer = AdapterTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=dataset["test"],
    compute_metrics=compute_accuracy,
)
```

I used previous compute accuracy to calculate f1_score but only accuracy return. Any suggestions for return predictions and labels and calculate classification report?

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works

```
def compute_accuracy(p: EvalPrediction):
  preds = np.argmax(p.predictions, axis=1)
  return {"acc": (preds == p.label_ids).mean()}}

load_accuracy = load_metric("accuracy")


def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
  predictions, labels = eval_pred
  predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
  print (classification_report(predictions, labels))
  return load_accuracy.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)
```